# Linphone IOS Build Issue

Tags: ios, build, xcode4.5, osx-mountain-lion, linphone

I am trying to compile linphone-iphone module on Mac Mountain Lion. Xcode version 4.5.

I followed the steps given in the following link http://shallwelearn.com/blog/?p=6.

I successfully crossed upto step4.

In Step5, I executed the command

```
    “make -f builder-iphone-simulator.mk all && make -f builder-iphone-os.mk all 
&&make -f builder-iphone-os.mk delivery-sdk”
```

I got the following Error:

```
checking whether res_ndestroy is declared… yes
checking for antlr3… no
configure: error: Could not find antlr.jar. Please install antlr3
make[1]: *** [/Hub/SIP_Implementation/IOS/workspace/linphone-iphone/submodules/build/../build-i386-apple-darwin/belle-sip/Makefile] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

So I downloaded the antlr.jar(version-3.5) and added classpath. But Still I am getting the same error.
Can anybody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue by executing “sudo port install antlr3″ command.

After executing this command, I execute the "make all". It is building without error

Comment: Linux users note that "port" is a Mac command. You will need to install antlr3 differently.